# str.replace() but new_string value should be from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to achieve the following,

```python
urls=["https://example1.com/test?para=123","https://example2.com/test?para=123","https://example3.com/test?para=123"]
payload=["<test>","<test123>","<test345>"]
for i in urls:
    for j in payloads:
        print(i)
        test=i.replace("=",'='+pyloads[j])
print('\n'+test)
```

where I should get out put like this

```
https://example1.com/test?para=<test>
https://example1.com/test?para=<test123>
https://example1.com/test?para=<test345>
https://example2.com/test?para=<test>
https://example2.com/test?para=<test123>
https://example2.com/test?para=<test345>
.
.
.
https://example3.com/test?para=<test345>
```

But it is not seems to be working I can't iterate through the list and use it in list.

Comment: You seem to be using three different names to reference the same array. It's defined as "payload", then you iterate using "payloads" and use "pyloads" in the replace method call. You also should not be using j as an index of the payload list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like

```py
urls=["https://example1.com/test?para=123","https://example2.com/test?para=123","https://example3.com/test?para=123"]
payload=["<test>","<test123>","<test345>"]
for i in urls:
    for j in payloads:
        print(i)
        test=i.replace("=",'='+j)
        print('\n'+test)
```

That is because `j` is not an loop index it's an element of the `payloads` array.

`for x in list` is an "foreach" iteration

Answer (score 1):

I will paste the fixed code here because there are a lot of problems to clear in this code.

```
urls=["https://example1.com/test?para=123","https://example2.com/test?para=123","https://example3.com/test?para=123"]
payload=["<test>","<test123>","<test345>"]
for i in urls:
    for j in payload:
        test=i.replace("=123", '='+j)
        print('\n'+test)
```

First of all, the pyloads identifier that you are using is not declared. You should use **payload** and the j in the `for j in payloads` is not a for loop but a foreach loop and return each value on every iteration instead of an index so instead of using `pyloads[j]` you should use only `j`. There are typos when you reference payload. You declared it as payload and referenced it as payloads and pyload at 2 diffeent scenarios

Second of all, in the replace function you are only replacing the `'='` sign. You are not replacing the 123 in url which would result in
`https://example1.com/test?para=123<test>`
instead of `https://example1.com/test?para=<test>`. So in the replace function, you should use `'=123'`

and last the print statements are misleading as you are first printing `i` before replacing anything which would result in lot of unnecessary printing. And when you print test you are printing it after you replaced each URL. so put the `print('\n'+test)` inside the foreach block

Answer (score 0):

```
urls=["https://example1.com/test?para=123","https://example2.com/test?para=123","https://example3.com/test?para=123"]
payload=["<test>","<test123>","<test345>"]
for i, val in enumerate(urls):
    res = f'{val}={payload[i]}'
    print (res)


Output:
https://example1.com/test?para=123=<test>
https://example2.com/test?para=123=<test123>
https://example3.com/test?para=123=<test345>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try string slicing:

```
urls = ["https://example1.com/test?para=123",
        "https://example2.com/test?para=123",
        "https://example3.com/test?para=123"]
payloads = ["<test>", "<test123>", "<test345>"]

for i in urls:
    i = i[:i.index('=')]
    for j in payloads:
        print(i + j)
```

Output:

```
https://example1.com/test?para<test>
https://example1.com/test?para<test123>
https://example1.com/test?para<test345>
https://example2.com/test?para<test>
https://example2.com/test?para<test123>
https://example2.com/test?para<test345>
https://example3.com/test?para<test>
https://example3.com/test?para<test123>
https://example3.com/test?para<test345>
```

The `str.replace()` method you used wouldn't replace the text that comes after the `=`, hence the slicing.